# "No devices available" in USB settings of guest OS

Tags: usb, sound, virtualbox, 15.10, virtualization

I am trying to connect my sound card and MIDI device directly to VirtualBox guest ***Windows 10*** 64-bit. I've done the following:

- Added current user to `vboxusers` group
- Installed VirtualBox 5.0.14 extension pack
- Restarted VirtualBox
- Re-Installed VirtualBox Guest Additions in the guest OS
- Reboot guest OS

However, i am not seeing any USB devices in VirtualBox and not able to connect them to the guest.

I select USB 2.0 or 3.0, no difference.
[image: USB Settings diag]

Tried listing USB devices:

```
username@computername:~$ VBoxManage list usbhost
Host USB Devices:

<none>
```

VirtualBox 5.0.14

Comment: I'm getting the exact same issue. Host Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding your account to vboxusers, it is not sufficient to restart VBox. Log off, log on again, then start Vbox.

Comment: Karel is correct, the driver is a pass-through driver, so the OS needs to enable it for it to work. The simplest way to get this to work on all OSs is to reboot.